# Why are all files (except index.php) being redirected to 'index.html'?

Tags: 7, .htaccess

We have a Drupal 7 Drupal Commerce site that we've just moved to our virtual private apache server, however we're seeing very strange behaviour that's making the site not work.

We're getting a strange problem where many files (images, CSS, JS) are getting "**307: Temporary redirect**"s to 'index.html', which doesn't even exist.

We have a very ordinary apache setup (no unusual settings), and the htaccess file of our website is straight from Drupal core - we haven't edited ourselves.

Is this a problem with the way we've set up Drupal, apache, DNS, or something else?

Comment: The issue should be in your server configuration. I've never faced such issue with the drupal. Check other than front page in your drupal site is accessible. If not, your server is not reading the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Almost definitely a server configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Rewrite Rule written in `.htaccess` as,

```
# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This may be your problem.

There are few assumptions that can be the reason why its happening :

- Please check the method you the using to access files.
- It might be your server issue which does not provide correct access rights for accessing the files
- Your files are not properly placed in correct locations.